# Starting the CSS type text Animation from Current Location instead of 0 width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to CSS Animations and am trying to get a text typing effect. I achieved it using references from various online tutorials.

Problem:
When I am adding this div inside my website container say 900px width with all things align to center, the animation starts from 0 px width, gets completed and awkwardly slides to align in the center.

I want the animation not to slide to center but rather start from the to be center position and end gracefully.

This is my code:

```css
body {
  width: 900px;
  text-align: center;
}
.typetext {
  /*  color: lime; */
  /*  font-family: "Courier";*/
  font-size: 20px;
  /*  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end);
}
.typetext:nth-child(2) {
  animation: type2 8s steps(60, end);
}
@keyframes type {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row lead typetext" id="anim5" style="clear:both; padding-top:10px; font-size:25px; font-weight:600;">
    <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">Getting you investment ready and focused on growth</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Please guide

Answer (score 1):

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg42bqn4/3/)

```css
body {
 
text-align:center;
}
.typetext {
  /*  color: lime; */
  /*  font-family: "Courier";*/
  font-size: 20px;
  /*  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
 
  -webkit-animation: type 5s;
}
@keyframes type {

0% {width: 0px;margin:0 auto;}
  100% {width: 100%; margin:0 auto;}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row lead typetext"  style="padding-top:10px; font-size:25px; font-weight:600;">
    <div>Getting you investment ready and focused on growth</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to start from the left. How Can I do this

Answer (score 0):

I added display: inline-block; to the .typetext  class. I hope that is what you aim for

```css
body {
  width: 900px;
  text-align: center;
}
.typetext {
  /*  color: lime; */
  /*  font-family: "Courier";*/
  font-size: 20px;
  /*  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end);
}
.typetext:nth-child(2) {
  animation: type2 8s steps(60, end);
}
@keyframes type {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row lead typetext" id="anim5" style="clear:both; padding-top:10px; font-size:25px; font-weight:600;">
    <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">Getting you investment ready and focused on growth</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: To some extent yes. But I want the text start/appear from left, not from right or center. Any way to do that

Comment: enclose the .typetext div to another div. Lets call this div .mycontainer.  .mycontainer{width: 600px; text-align: left; margin: 0 auto;}. This works but you need to now the length of the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .typetext {
  /*  color: lime; */
  /*  font-family: "Courier";*/
  font-size: 20px;
  /*  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 565px;
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end);
}
```

Comment: Nope. It just reduces the whole div not center it nor displays full text

Answer (score 0):

```
    ![<style>
body {
  width: 900px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
.typetext {
  /*  color: lime; */
  /*  font-family: "Courier";*/
  font-size: 20px;
  /*  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 565px;
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end);
}
.typetext:nth-child(2) {
  animation: type2 8s steps(60, end);
}
@keyframes type {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="row lead typetext" id="anim5" style="clear:both; padding-top:10px; font-size:25px; font-weight:600; margin: 0 165px">
    <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">Getting you investment ready and focused on growth</div>
  </div>
</body>][1]
```